# Matplotlib / PyQT4: transparent figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4

I am using Python with PyQt4 and I want to embed a matplotlib figure in the GUI.
What's important to me, is that the background of the `Figure` matches the background color of the GUI. (no grey background around the actual plot)

My partial solution would be to make the `Figure` transparent with the following code:

```
...
fig.patch.set_alpha(0.5)
...
```

This works fine when plotting in pylab mode, but when embedding in PyQt4, the re-rendering doesn't clear the old figure, but adds it with on top with transparency I give. As seen in the sample below, which is the result of resizing the window:

[image: no working sample]

The sample was produced using the [code from the matplotlib website](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html) with adding the `set_alpha(0.5)` line in the `__init__` statement of `MyMplCanvas`.

Comment: It is best to paste all the code you used here instead of only providing links.  Other pages can change which will make your question ill-posed.

Comment: also cut it down to the _minimum_ needed to show your problem.

Comment: thanks for the hints. you're right about reducing the problem and posting it directly on SO. Its just in that case I wanted to show that the problem occurs even with the official recipe and not only my potentially wrong way.

Comment: in this case, I think the right thing to have done was to post the official code stripped down to just the dynamic graph portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found an interesting bug in `matplotlib`.  The `Qt4` backend does not clear the `qImage` it uses to display the figure before redrawing, hence the reason you see the shadows.  This is easily fixed by adding a few lines to `matplotlib.backends.backed_qt4Agg.FigureCanvasQTAgg.paintEvent`

```
def paintEvent(self, e):
    """
    Copy the image from the Agg canvas to the qt.drawable.
    In Qt, all drawing should be done inside of here when a widget is
    shown onscreen.
    """

    #FigureCanvasQT.paintEvent(self, e)
    if DEBUG:
        print('FigureCanvasQtAgg.paintEvent: ', self,
            self.get_width_height())

    if self.blitbox is None:
        # matplotlib is in rgba byte order.  QImage wants to put the bytes
        # into argb format and is in a 4 byte unsigned int.  Little endian
        # system is LSB first and expects the bytes in reverse order
        # (bgra).
        if QtCore.QSysInfo.ByteOrder == QtCore.QSysInfo.LittleEndian:
            stringBuffer = self.renderer._renderer.tostring_bgra()
        else:
            stringBuffer = self.renderer._renderer.tostring_argb()

        refcnt = sys.getrefcount(stringBuffer)

        qImage = QtGui.QImage(stringBuffer, self.renderer.width,
                              self.renderer.height,
                              QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        rect = qImage.rect()    ### <-- added this line
        p = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        p.eraseRect(rect)       ### <-- added this line
        p.drawPixmap(QtCore.QPoint(0, 0), QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qImage))

        # draw the zoom rectangle to the QPainter
        if self.drawRect:
            p.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 1, QtCore.Qt.DotLine))
            p.drawRect(self.rect[0], self.rect[1],
                       self.rect[2], self.rect[3])
        p.end()

        # This works around a bug in PySide 1.1.2 on Python 3.x,
        # where the reference count of stringBuffer is incremented
        # but never decremented by QImage.
        # TODO: revert PR #1323 once the issue is fixed in PySide.
        del qImage
        if refcnt != sys.getrefcount(stringBuffer):
            _decref(stringBuffer)
    else:
        bbox = self.blitbox
        l, b, r, t = bbox.extents
        w = int(r) - int(l)
        h = int(t) - int(b)
        t = int(b) + h
        reg = self.copy_from_bbox(bbox)
        stringBuffer = reg.to_string_argb()
        qImage = QtGui.QImage(stringBuffer, w, h,
                              QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qImage)
        p = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        p.drawPixmap(QtCore.QPoint(l, self.renderer.height-t), pixmap)
        p.end()
        self.blitbox = None
    self.drawRect = False
```

Changes in diff form:

```
diff --git a/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py b/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py
index 8433731..718d352 100644
--- a/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py
+++ b/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py
@@ -118,7 +118,9 @@ class FigureCanvasQTAgg(FigureCanvasQT, FigureCanvasAgg):
             qImage = QtGui.QImage(stringBuffer, self.renderer.width,
                                   self.renderer.height,
                                   QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
+            rect = qImage.rect()
             p = QtGui.QPainter(self)
+            p.eraseRect(rect)
             p.drawPixmap(QtCore.QPoint(0, 0), QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qImage))

             # draw the zoom rectangle to the QPainter
```

You can either modify your local installation or monkey patch it in your code.

[PR #2449](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2449) which has been merged and will be in 1.3.1