# matplotlib and pyqt4 transparent background

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt4

For my app I'm trying to use matplotlib together with PyQt4. I tried to make the background of the matplotlib figures transparent as in [Matplotlib / PyQT4: transparent figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944561/matplotlib-pyqt4-transparent-figure)
However the result is this:

[image] while the background is like this:

[image]

It's like the background is rescaled in the matplotlib figure or a part of the background of the QWidget in PyQT4 is copied to another place.
it's very difficult to make the code short. I will take 1 example from 1 graph:

```
 class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
     """Ultimately, this is a QWidget (as well as a FigureCanvasAgg)."""
     def __init__(self, parent=None):
         fig = Figure(facecolor='None',edgecolor='None')
         self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111,autoscale_on=False,axisbg='none')
         self.fig.patch.set_alpha(0)
```

The rest of the code is based on the example on Matplotlib
http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html

I have not been able to solve this problem. So is it possible to make the background really transparent ?

Comment: Your OS/window manager? Does transparency work as expected in any other qt-based apps?

Comment: @mdurant I tried this on different OS. All have the same result.

Comment: Sorry, I am mystified.

Comment: The answer to this question is now given at [this new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631428/matplotlib-and-transparency-figure) which did provide a [mcve] of the issue and was thus rather easily solvable.

Comment: Due the newer question having that mcve, I think we can therefore close this question as a duplicate of the newer one (even if it is chronologically inverted).